# Dispatch Planner Optimization Problem using Google OR-Tools for Open VRP

Tags: optimization, routes, or-tools

I have been assigned a project related to VRP in which I have a fleet of trucks scattered in different locations that need to pick up and deliver goods from and to different locations.
Google's OR tools works on using depot for optimization, but in my case there is no starting or ending depot and I need to create a planner that can find the optimised routes for all the vehicles with different constraints.
Im struggling to find a solution for such problem, please help for the same.